# How to convert a String to int on assert

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, assert, string

Assert cannot be able to find value because it's expecting a String but an integer is present instead. How can I be able to convert this String to an integer.

I tried using Integer.parseInt(number) but it is ignored.

```
@Then("^User assert \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void userAssertAnd(String Qty, String Price)  {
String Quantity = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[8]/div/input[@class='form-control']")).getText();
AssertJUnit.assertEquals(Quantity, Qty);

String modifierPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[9]/div/input[@class='form-control GEHR2AJDHI']")).getText();
AssertJUnit.assertEquals(modifierPrice, Price);
```

Comment: "I tried using Integer.parseInt(number) but it is ignored." what do you mean under "ignored"? And in which line do you experience the issue? As it seems from your code you compare String to String. There should not be type mismatches

Comment: Also please do not start variable names from capital letters. There is a convention in Java world to name only Types from uppercase, variables should start from lowercase.

Comment: I'm getting error: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<> but was:<120> and I also tried String Quantity = String.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[8]/div/input[@class='form-control']")).getText()); and the same error persists

Comment: It is not connected with whether you convert value to int or not. There are two strings one of which is empty. You need to do some debugging to know why that happens

Answer (score 1):

To get the string value of an int, you can use: `String.valueOf(int)`